# Why couldn't the guardians leave the infinity stone with the collector?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

I've done a little research regarding the collector, and he's supposedly one of the most powerful beings in the marvel comics universe.  If that's the case, wouldn't the orb have been safe with him?  Why did the guardians feel like they had to take the stone someplace else when they could have left it with such a powerful being and gotten paid?  The aether seems to be safe with the Collector, and the asgardians seemed to think it was safe to leave the aether with him, so why couldn't the orb have been left with him?

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, the obvious answer is the Collector just had his whole collection blown to smithereens *due* to the infinity stone. Obviously he is not able to control the destructive power of the stone. Seeing as how it was too much for him, they needed to leave it in other hands. I would also wonder at this point if the Asgardians  might want to rethink their leaving things with the Collector as well ... he's not quite as dependable as previously thought.

Comment: While this makes sense, it would have to mean the cinematic universe Collector is but a shadow of the powerful being from the comics universe.  Further just because he was betrayed by his closest servant, doesn't necessarily mean he cannot handle valuable or powerful objects.  In face, if he couldn't handle powerful objects, his entire character would no longer have a story or reason to exist.  Also, what makes the nova corps capable of keeping the stone more safe than the collector could?

Comment: James Gunn deliberately made many characters in his Guardians movies different from their comic book counterparts, which he admits to in numerous sources (for example, in "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2" audio commentary). If Drax, Yondu and Taserface are all different in the movies than in the comics, why wouldn't The Collector be as well?